# Brightness Problem in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: brightness

- whenever i turn on ubuntu brightness increases to 100% always. i
  manually have to lower it to somewhat around 60%.how to set it
  permanently to your choice,so that whenever i turn on ubuntu it
  remains 60%? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Under "System Settings" (in the system menu) there is an item called "Brightness and Locks" (or similar, my Ubuntu is not in English so I have to translate). Its icon is a screen with a padlock. Under this item you can change screen brightness with a slide bar. Do you mean this when you say "lower it manually"?

On my dual-screen system this slide bar changes only the build-in screen, though.